# How to stack two UL classes directly on top of one another in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css, class, center

I'm attempting to center both of these so that the middle image is directly in the center and the text in "nav navbar-nav" is centered as well, not beginning at the word "BSM".

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <img src="insertimage">
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li><a href="/">BSM <strong>PROJECT</strong> CONNECT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've had success centering with left-margin 50% in the CSS, but have had no luck with the z-index. How do I have both objects directly in the center of the page with the image directly and evenly on top of the words?

CSS:

```
div.collapse.navbar-collapse {
  text-align:left;
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: It will be helpful if we can reproduce the issue you're having. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29550881/edit) to include your CSS code.

Comment: Sorry and thank you. I've added the CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @showdev says would be helpful to see your css, try in the parent container set a width and add margin:0 auto. Also I don't see the point of using a Ul with the image if this one is not inside a li tag.

Other Ways you can also use text-align: center with the parent element.

Comment: I add the CSS above, but your advice for taking the image out of the UL tag pretty much sealed it for me. I was able to work with that and discovered there was another selector that was giving me problems. So, thank you!